# Cookie issues (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I think I must be having a brain freeze because for the life of me, I can't seem to understand this.  I am using CodeIgniter to set  cookie for a Facebook status.  When a user first lands on a fan page and isn't a fan, I set the cookie to "NOT LIKED YET".  Then, when the user likes the page, the page is reloaded and the cookie is checked for a value.  If the cookie exists and the value is "NOT LIKED YET", I set the cookie to "ALREADY LIKED".

Somehow, when I trace the cookie in Firebug, it always says "NOT LIKED YET" although the headers for the page clearly shows the cookie value has changed.  Any ideas what I am doing incorrectly?

```
if ($fan_page_liked == '')
    {
        $this->_set_cookie_for_conversion('NOT LIKED YET');
        $data['before_like'] = $this->config->item('before_like_image');
    } else if($fan_page_liked == 1)
    {
        $after_like_cookie = get_cookie($facebook_cookie);
        if ($after_like_cookie == 'NOT LIKED YET')
        {
            $this->_set_cookie_for_conversion('ALREADY LIKED');
        }
    }

private function _set_cookie_for_conversion($value)
{
    $this->load->helper('cookie');
    $facebook_cookie = $this->config->item('facebook_like_cookie');
    $cookie = array(
        'name' => $facebook_cookie,
        'value' => $value,
        'expire' => '86500'
    );
    set_cookie($cookie);
}
```

[image: See image to check out the headers and then the resulting stuff in Firecookie]

Comment: When you say the headers show, what headers? The request headers or the response headers? Are all the requests and responses occurring on the same domain (including subdomain, i.e. always with or without www)?

Comment: please see the above image.  I just included it.  The response header shows the cookie with "ALREADY LIKED".  Then in Firecookie, I see "Not Liked yet"

Comment: I kind of get the feeling that your cookie is being set, but Firecookie hasn't updated or something else strange (like an old cookie). Check in firebug what cookie header is sent in the next request to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I closed my browser, went to bed and then when I reopened the project the next day, the cookies worked as coded.  Perhaps Firecookie went  a little crazy since I had the same browser window was open the entire day?

Thanks for everyone's help.